# Wordpress (page builder) Switch divs on collapse to mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a page in Wordpress (with the Site Origin Page Builder plugin) that looks like this:

(■=image
t=text)

■-t

t-■

■-t

on collapse it looks like this:

■

t

t

■

■

t

What I want is:

■

t

■

t

■

t

In order to achieve this I need to switch every `:odd` first and second div around on screens smaller as 770 pixels width. I need it to work out of the box so my client can do his own stuff without worrying about the layout. This it the page: http://darylkeep.com/blog Here's what I have. I feel like i'm pretty close:

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){

  var width = $('body').width();
  var strDiv1Cont = $(".panel-grid:odd div:eq(0)").html();
  var strDiv2Cont = $(".panel-grid:odd div:eq(1)").html();

  if(width < 770){

    $(".panel-grid:odd div:eq(0)").html(strDiv2Cont);
    $(".panel-grid:odd div:eq(1)").html(strDiv1Cont);

 }else{
    $(".panel-grid:odd div:eq(0)").html(strDiv1Cont);
    $(".panel-grid:odd div:eq(1)").html(strDiv2Cont);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this won't help you as much as I want to, but I won't hide this answer. maybe it still helps. looking at the code I am assuming you're using Site Origin Pagebuilder, right? (there are a lot of pagebuilders out there)

As far as I know, SO does not support this case. Sadly. So what I've done for my theme is using 
https://github.com/chasecmiller/Foundation-6-and-SiteOrigin-Panels and extended it to output the PageBuilder as Foundation6 Code.

In foundation 6 you have an option for what you want: 
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html -> Source Ordering

Next you could write a custom widget where the user can select where to the element should be on mobile (top or bottom) -> I've been doing this a lot to reveal the full pagebuilder power.

I know you'd have to do a freakin lot to use this solution. But looking at your theme, sorry for that!, it's not that special / hard so you could restart. Using Foundation you should be pretty fast building the current layout visible under http://darylkeep.com/blog/

Hope this helps you out in any way.... even if it's for the next project.

all the best

Comment: I'm currently using Wonderflux, not Foundation. The site is 99.99% done so my boss would certainly not be pleased if I switch things around now. If stackoverflow can not provide an answer I will use the way that is more difficult for my client. Would you recommend Foundation? I may use it in my next project

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using JavaScript but pure CSS using relative positioning.

In your sites case **.panel-grid-cell** is the column, you make every layout as 
image + text in your composer

```
.panel-grid,.panel-grid-cell {
    position: relative
}
.panel-grid .panel-grid-cell:first-child{
    left:70%; /*the width of the text column*/
}
.panel-grid .panel-grid-cell + .panel-grid-cell{
    right:30%; /*the image container width*/
}
```

Of course you can add another class to the first panel to avoid this from happening.